# How to find out when I have reached the end of a rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

Okay so I have multiple `GameObjects` that I rotate toward. I am trying to see if `playerAgentBase.transform.rotation == lookRotation`.

The problem I am having is that sometimes the `playerAgentBase` rotation has negative values while `lookRotation` has positive values. So the if statement never becomes `true`. I am not sure why this is happening. Sometimes this works and other times it don't. When it doesn't work it rotates toward the wrong object.

Is there a better way to check when my rotation has reached its destination?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```c#
private void Start()
{
    rotate = true;
}

public void RotateTowards()
{
    float strength = 1.5f;
    float str = 0f;

    if (playerAgentBase != null)
    {
        Vector3 direction = (transform.position - playerAgentBase.transform.position);
        direction.y = 0;
        str = Mathf.Min(strength * Time.deltaTime, 1);
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
        playerAgentBase.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(playerAgentBase.transform.rotation, lookRotation, 10f);
        //Here is where my problem is  
        if (playerAgentBase.transform.rotation == lookRotation) //<-------------------
         {
             rotate = false;
             InteractA();
         }
     }
 }

 public void Update()
 {
     if (rotate)
     {
         RotateTowards();
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think you may want to reread the documentation for [`Quaternion.Slerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html). Take note that `float t` is clamped in the range of [0, 1], meaning if you pass in 10f, it's going to snap to the second rotation immediately.

Comment: To compare two Quaternions look at [Quaternion.Angle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Angle.html). E.g. `if (Quaternion.Angle(quA, quB) <= thresholdAngle) ....` => don't use `0` but maybe something like `0.001`. The value is in degrees so this should be fine enough